# Question regarding weights in a Model

Tags: machine-learning

Let's take a Linear regression model.I just want to know are weights the same for every row once the model is trained? Or are weights vector or an array for eg I have data X= [4,5] four rows and 5 features will the weights W be the same for every row or it is has a different value for every row?

I am a beginner so please spare me these basic questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basic regression setup, the weights are a function of the whole of the training dataset therefore they are the same for every row.